# Record-and-play web apps load/stress testing

Tags: software-testing, performance-analysis

I am looking for a load/stress testing software/platform that allows to:

1. Record user activity in a web browser into a script, and then replay it (or that can accept third-party scripts e.g. [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)));
2. Modify the script e.g. set random values for emails/passwords instead of those initially typed;
3. Upload the script to the cloud, configure load test (number of users, ramp up time etc.), perform it and produce report.

So far I have found a few options that seem to closely resemble what I want:

1. [LoadView](https://www.dotcom-monitor.com/load-testing/). Uses a custom script language that can absorb additional C# lines of code. This is so far the only option that worked well for me;
2. [LoadBooster](https://www.loadbooster.com). Seems to be able to use Selenium HTML scripts as load testing scenarios (the scripts need to be pre-recorded using Selenium IDE Firefox plugin or similar). The script I recorded became stuck though when I tried to verify it for load-testing — I'll see if I can progress further;
3. [Web Performance Load Tester](https://www.webperformance.com/load-testing-tools/pro-features.html). I managed to record a user session, but then could not immediately figure out how to set some of the field values to be random. The interface is all point-and-click, and the actual underlying script doesn't seem to be available for raw editing;
4. [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com/website-load-testing-tools/). Uses JavaScript for scripting which is good. However, after recording a user session, it requires to perform a "[correlation](http://www.radview.com/about-webload/features/correlation/)" which is to ensure that all dynamic values (session IDs, tokens etc.) are set right for load testing. This step is confusing because, when using a real browser, all those values are generated automatically and this is what I basically want the load test to do (and this is what, for example, LoadView does). In other words, there should be no need to worry about configuring those values.

While I will be digging the Options 2-4 further to see if they can do what I want, and also look out for other options, can someone please:

1. Recommend any suitable options that I have missed?
2. Advise if the Options 2-4 can actually do what I want and therefore are worth digging further.